# Node-RED node [httpInMultipart]: Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'

Tags: node-red

I have tried to use the httpInMultipart node in Node-RED, however after I add the the `"node-red-contrib-http-multipart":"0.1.x"` in my package.json dependancy, after restarting the node-red, there's one error message:

```
[httpInMultipart] Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
```

This resulting in the httpInMultipart node not shown up in the node-red pallet.

I've tried to add the `"body-parser":"1.15.x"` in my package.json, but it still doesn't work and have the same error message...

Comment: From a brief look at the node it seams to have a number of issues, like this one and the fact it includes all of node-red again as a dependency. I would suggest raising a bug with the developer via the email in the package.json as they don't seam to have included a github repository for the node

Answer (score 0):

I just pushed an update (version 0.2.0) that cleans up the packaging and adds dependencies that aren't present in node-red <0.13.

The 0.1.x line of the plugin should work for node-red >0.13 because it uses the same dependencies already in node-red, but it definitely needed cleanup.  node-red <0.13 didn't include the body-parser plugin as part of it's dependencies so that's likely the issue.

Feel free to contribute via pull requests (https://github.com/sax1johno/node-red-contrib-http-multipart) and report issues (https://github.com/sax1johno/node-red-contrib-http-multipart/issues).

Comment: Thanks John for the prompt update, the node is shown up now. it works

Comment: @whyfun excellent - glad to hear it.  Don't forget to accept the answer so others know that it fixed the problem for you.